# MotionLayout setTransition() always calls transitionToStart()

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

Using `MotionLayout`, I need to temporarily transition to a **loading state** (`ConstraintSet`), which I do by calling:

```
motionLayout.transitionToState(R.id.state_loading)
```

Then I want to transition back to the default `Transition` declared in my `MotionScene` XML:

```
motionLayout.transitionToState(R.id.state_expanded)
```

The problem comes now when I want to restore the default behavior by setting an `endState` calling:

```
motionLayout.setTransition(R.id.state_expanded, R.id.state_collapsed)
```

The issue here is that [`setTransition(int beginId, int endId)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/motion/MotionLayout.html#setTransition(int,%2520int)) also calls `transitionToStart()`, animating it again in a weird manner.

So my question is if there is any way to call `setTransition()` without calling `transitionToStart()`?

Answer (score 1):

I found an ugly way to do this by creating a custom `MotionLayout`, just to make [`setTransition(Transition transition)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/motion/MotionLayout.html#setTransition(android.support.constraint.motion.MotionScene.Transition)) method public (since it's `protected` but it won't call `transitionToStart()`):

```
class CustomMotionLayout : MotionLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet)

    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr)

    public override fun setTransition(transition: MotionScene.Transition) {
        super.setTransition(transition)
    }
}
```

Then retrieving your `Transition` by Id and passing it to the new public method:

```
val desiredTransition = customMotionLayout.getTransition(R.id.transition_default)
customMotionLayout.setTransition(desiredTransition)
```

This way, when setting a `Transition` programmatically to a `MotionLayout`, it won't call `transitionToStart()`.

Comment: I got the same issue, really annoying. But my problem is after invoke `setTransition(beginId, endId)` it will always move to the end `ConstraintSet`

Comment: ```motion:autoTransition="none"```  worked for me in Transition tag